# Can I invoke the Linux Terminal with .net

Tags: .net, shell, ubuntu, command-line-interface

**Current situation**

I have some Servers which do automatic hard disk management (init disk, mount disk, fix disk,  ...) These Servers are running on Ubuntu Server latest long term build.

Originally I started out with bash scripts but it quickly turned out that my knowledge of bash scripting is somewhat limited and I got a frustrated with the text processing capabilities.

Hence I used, what I know (.net) and established an ssh connection. With that SSH connection I can run commands such as `"lsblk -O -b --j"` and process their output to format the drives, edit the fstab file or basically whatever I want to do in order to manage the server.

**Goal**

My goal is to move away from ssh connection on my local machine and create a software which I can implement as a service on the target server itself.

I guess I could open an ssh connection to local host. Is that some appropriate workaround or is there another way to hook up my program to the shell?

In Windows, something similar than this could be used to invoke commands against cmd:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

// The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
// This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
// Do not create the black window.
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
// Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
// Get the output into a string
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
// Display the command output.
Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
  catch (Exception objException)
  {
  // Log the exception
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it is relatively similar to Windows.

I have written a relatively simple class, which can be used to fire commands against the shell.
Github repo here: https://github.com/forReason/UnixCommandInvokeHelper_Solution

```
public class Command
{
    public Command(string commandString, string workingDirectory = "./")
    { 
        CommandText = commandString;
        WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
    }
    public string CommandText { get; set; }
    public string WorkingDirectory { get; set; }
    public string Errors { get; private set; }
    public string Output { get; private set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; private set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; private set; }
    public async void Execute()
    {
        StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        Errors = "";
        Output = "";

        var process = new Process();
        try
        {
            string escapedArgs = CommandText.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                FileName = $"/bin/bash",
                WorkingDirectory = this.WorkingDirectory,
                Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };
            process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
            process.Start();
            Errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            Output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Errors = ex.Message;
        }
        process.Close();
        EndTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```